# Open a silverlight window in a new tab

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight window, and when a button is pressed, I want to open it on a new tab\window. How can I do it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The only thing you can open 'in a new tab' is a web page. If you want to open a different Silverlight application in a new tab, then it will need to be hosted in a webpage, and you will need to use HtmlPage.Window.Navigate() to open that page. You cannot just open a new tab and have it somehow contain something embedded in your application - that is not how webbrowsers work.

Comment: i wrote HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:52878/DoNationFinalTestPage.aspx#/jjj"), "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip");  is the window that i built, but it opens the application again in a new window and not the "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip" window

Answer (score 14):

The `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate()` method has an overload which allows you to specify which frame to load the new page in. `_blank` is used for new window/tab.

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://google.com"), "_blank");
```

Comment: but its not google or something like that, its a window i created, so what's the URL i need to put there?

Comment: but i don't have URL! that's the point, it's just a window that i created, so it dos'nt has URL, or does it?

Comment: i wrote HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:52878/DoNationFinalTestPage.aspx#/jjj"), "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip");  is the window that i built, but it opens the application again in a new window and not the "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip" window

Answer (score 7):

Taking your question literally the answer is:-

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "_blank");
```

Comment: but there is no mention to the window that need to be open.
let say the name of my window is app, how does it fit un what you wrote?

Comment: @aharont: IF the window name is "app" then change "_blank" to "app"

Comment: LIKE THIS: 
HtmlPage.Window.Navigat(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "OrganiztrionInfoFromToolTip"); ?

it open me the program again, not my window...

Comment: i wrote HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:52878/DoNationFinalTestPage.aspx#/jjj"), "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip");  is the window that i built, but it opens the application again in a new window and not the "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip" window

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the URI like people here are suggesting you should just create an object of your page and pass it to the navigate method.

```
Dim yournewpage as new OrganiztrionInfoFromToolTip()
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(yournewpage, "_blank")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for this.

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://www.silverlight.net" TargetName="_blank" Content="HyperlinkButton"/>
```

When you specify "_blank" as TargetName. A new tab or window is opened and the specified uri gets opened. Also other values for TargetName are valid. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton.targetname%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) more.

**Edit:**

To open the same Silverlight application in a new tab you can use the [System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.browser.htmldocument.documenturi%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) as NavigationUri of the HyperlinkButton.

Comment: and where is the window fit in?
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.myWindow?

Comment: @aharont: I don´t understand what mean?

Comment: ok, if my window is called orgTip, how can i open it with the line you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Also try this in .aspx Page

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Your Applicateion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var windowClose = window.close;
        window.close = function () {
            window.open("", "_self");
            windowClose();
        }
        function OpenWindow() {
            window.opener = 'x';
            window.close();            
            window.open('Default.html', '_blank', 'status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,directories=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,height=' + screen.availHeight + ',width=' + screen.availWidth + ',top=0,left=0');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OpenWindow();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
```